# PHP Get value from config array

Tags: php

I have a config.php file that looks like this

```
return array(
"array1"=>
    array(
      "array2"=>"value"
    )
);
```

How can I dynamically extract array2 value using a function like this?

```
function getConfigValue(?)
{
    $config = include("config.php");
    return $config....  
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$path  = 'array1.array2';
$value = array_reduce(
    explode('.', $path),
    function (array $value, $key) { return $value[$key]; },
    $config
);
```

Comment: Be aware that this method throws an error if you access a key which is not in the array. You could improve the function by adding `if(isset($value[$key]) === false) return null;` to the beginning of the anonymous function. So you get `NULL` instead of a warning message.

Comment: actually i've used a particular php framework which also utilizes this kind of style in calling configs. +1 brilliant answer

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Yes, this could certainly use more obvious error messages. However, the `array` type hint will let your program error out completely, no need for `isset`. If you don't want hard errors but want to soft-fail instead, a manual check may be better. Depends on your priorities and design goals here.